# What does "/bin/sh -c nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily" mean?

Tags: shell, security, cron, nice, sleep

Today, when I logged in and checked the `ps` output, I noticed
a few lines that were run automatically under the `root`.
I grepped the relevant lines here:

```
root      1126  0.0  0.0   2616   424 ?        Ss   Apr16   0:06 cron
root      6445  0.0  0.0   2400   868 ?        Ss   07:30   0:00 anacron -s
root      6566  0.0  0.0   2244   276 ?        S    07:35   0:00 /bin/sh -c nice run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
root      6567  0.0  0.0   2152   524 ?        SN   07:35   0:00 run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
root      6574  0.0  0.0   2244   556 ?        SN   07:35   0:00 /bin/sh /etc/cron.daily/apt
root      6615  0.0  0.0   2160   272 ?        SN   07:35   0:00 sleep 1721
```

I haven't been using cron on this machine for a long time (years), so don't remember I started it on the 16th April. What is the meaning of those commands in sequence? Could it be a security issue?

Comment: Did you boot your system on April 16 by any chance?

Comment: @StephenKitt `uptime` is 24 days, so it looks like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not personally be using `cron`, but the system uses it for essential maintenance tasks, such as rotating log files that have grown too big or too old, checking disk quotas, doing consistency checks, making sure permissions on essential files are correct, or mailing the root user differences between important configuration files that have changed since last run (this differs a lot between systems).

*Never try to disable `cron`.  It will prevent essential tasks from running on your system.*

If you look in `/etc/cron.daily` you will find all the system maintenance tasks that are run on a daily basis.  On some systems there is also a corresponding weekly and/or monthly lists of tasks.

- `anacron` is a program that is often used on machines that aren't up and running all the time.  It is likely that your system uses it to schedule the daily tasks (possibly via `cron`). It makes sure that daily tasks are run at least once daily (whereas `cron` requires the machine to be up and running at specific times to run tasks).
- `run-parts` is a Linux thing that runs multiple scripts in a directory in sequence (e.g. all scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`).
- `/etc/cron.daily/apt` is the currently running maintenance task, obviously having something to do with your package manager `apt` (possibly doing some update of either packages or of the list of available security updates or something similar).
- The `sleep` may be a delay before the next task is run, if it is related at all.

In short: nothing to worry about, but do have a look at those things in `/etc/cron.daily` just to inform yourself about how your system works.

Comment: And running "nice" without a niceness it probably defaults to 10 whereas the default niceness of a process is probably 0, so all of the cron scripts could run with a lower priority than other processes without a niceness specified (priority up to the kernel)